# how to display watermark text on pdf or existing pdf using itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

Help me to display watermark text on pdf  using itextsharp in asp.net
Thanks,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [**this**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=518686) for your question which clears some doubt of u regarding your question.

Comment: @Sunil patil, in the link which i have given the code is written in VB.net by "Stanav". Try the code once. And if u want to convert ur code to C# u can use 
  [1]: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/#convert-code

Comment: While this answer is several years old now and this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[link for pdfsharp dll](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/downloads/get/351367)
with pdfsharp
'import this

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
    Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
    Imports PdfSharp.Drawing

    Dim doc = ReturnCompatiblePdf(path_of_pdf_file)
    Dim document As New PdfDocument
    document = PdfReader.Open(doc, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)
    Dim watermark As String = "This is my watermark"

    For Each page_ As PdfPage In document.Pages

        Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page_, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append)
        Dim fontx As New XFont("Trebuchet MS", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
        Dim posx, posy As Double
        posx = (page_.Width.Value - watermark.Length) / 2
        posy = page_.Height.Value - 8
        gfx.TranslateTransform(posx, posy)
        gfx.DrawString(watermark, fontx, XBrushes.Black, New XPoint(1, 1), XStringFormats.Default)
    Next

    If File.Exists(save_path) = False Then
        document.Save(save_path)
    End If
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a solution "using itextsharp". Your solution is for pdfsharp. Do you want to imply that pdfsharp is a part of itextsharp?

Comment: No, pdfcharp is not part of itextsharp. I have encountered the same difficulties with itextsharp, the workaround is to use pdfcharp just for this feature, so I use both dll in my program each has these advantages and these limits that is complete, with both dll we have more leeway for handling pdf files